# KineticJS drag multiple images without grouping them

Tags: javascript, canvas, kineticjs

is it possible to drag all children elements of a layer without grouping them?

I have different layers with image-elements and a path shape. The path draws a bubble around the images. If the user drag the bubble to another place, all images should move there, too.

But it should be also possible to drag a single element. 
At the moment, it is possible to drag a single element and to drag the bubble, but there is no combination...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes, you can drag "related" nodes when a "container" node is dragged:**

- add a class to all children of a bubble (for example, each child's name:"bubble1")
- on bubble `dragstart`, save the bubble's starting position
- on bubble `dragmove`, calculate how far the bubble has been dragged and reposition all related elements by that same distance

Example code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/Zr6TE/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prototype</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v5.0.1.min.js"></script>

<style>
body{padding:20px;}
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:350px;
  height:350px;
}
</style>        
<script>
$(function(){

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 350,
        height: 350
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    stage.add(layer);

    var bubble=new Kinetic.Circle({
        x:100,
        y:100,
        width:100,
        height:100,
        fill:"blue",
        draggable:true,
    });
    bubble.lastPos;
    bubble.on("dragstart",function(){
        this.lastPos=this.position();
    });
    bubble.on("dragmove",function(){
        var lastPos=bubble.lastPos;
        var pos=bubble.position();
        var deltaX=pos.x-lastPos.x;
        var deltaY=pos.y-lastPos.y;
        layer.find(".bubble1").each(function(child){
            child.position({x:child.x()+deltaX, y:child.y()+deltaY} );
        });
        bubble.lastPos=pos;
        layer.draw();
    });
    layer.add(bubble);

    var circle1 = new Kinetic.Circle({
        x:80,
        y:80,
        radius:15,
        fill: 'red',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 4,
        draggable: true,
        name:"bubble1"
    });
    layer.add(circle1);

    //
    var circle2 = new Kinetic.Circle({
        x:110,
        y:110,
        radius:15,
        fill: 'green',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 4,
        draggable: true,
        name:"bubble1"
    });
    layer.add(circle2);

    //
    layer.draw();

}); // end $(function(){});

</script>       
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi @markE , I tried to adapt this code to my project and I failed :( here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/GLFxF/36/ , can you please tell me what's missing?

Comment: Ouch! That's 300+ lines of code.  I'd be glad to look at smaller code that outlines your problem.

Comment: Okay, here, I made it as short as I could http://jsfiddle.net/v778S/1/ if you like, go directly to the `dragend` event of the room object (the rectangle)

Comment: Kinetic.Groups really are the best way of containing a set of shapes/images.  You could reproduce group behavior using the code in my answer above. But Groups are really the way to group your set of shapes/images. You can use the dragend event to have the dropped clone join any rectangle group that it is dropped into:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/7BkR7/