# Possible to detect collisions of Paths or Kinetic Blobs/Layers?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I have multiple layers on my stage. Each layer contains images surrounded with a [blub](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-blob-tutorial/) ( see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22480234/kineticjs-drag-multiple-images-without-grouping-them)). Each blub is draggable.

Is it possible to detect collisions between the blubs while moving them?
I don't want to have overlapping bubbles, but rather if they collide, they should melt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can determine if blobs are colliding.**

There are at least 2 methods:

- calculate the bounding box for all blobs and test if the bounding boxes collide.
- draw each blob on a separate offscreen canvas and use pixel testing to see if they collide.

The bounding box method is faster.

The pixel-testing method is more precise, but slower are requires many more resources.

*An example:*

**Here's how to calculate and test if 2 blob bounding boxes are colliding.**

A Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/9tB7d/

**Start with a Kinetic Blob**

```
var blueBlob = new Kinetic.Line({
   points: [73,140,340,23,500,109,300,170],
   stroke: 'blue',
   strokeWidth: 10,
   fill: '#aaf',
   tension: 0.8,
   closed: true
});
```

That blob is made up of a set of Bezier curves.

**Get the Bezier curves that make up the blob:**

```
function kineticBlob2Beziers(blob){
    var beziers=[];
    var start=blob.getPoints();
    var pts=blob.getTensionPoints();
    var n=0;
    var lastN=pts.length-2;
    var sx=start[0];
    var sy=start[1];
    while(n<lastN){
        bez={
            s: {x:sx,y:sy},
            c1:{x:pts[n++],y:pts[n++]},
            c2:{x:pts[n++],y:pts[n++]},
            e: {x:pts[n++],y:pts[n++]}
        };
        beziers.push(bez);
        sx=pts[n-2];
        sy=pts[n-1];
    }
    return(beziers);
}
```

**Calculate the blobs bounding box using its Bezier curves:**

```
function getBlobBB(beziers){
    var minX=1000000;
    var minY=1000000;
    var maxX=-1000000;
    var maxY=-1000000;
    for(var i=0;i<beziers.length;i++){
        var bez=beziers[i];
        for(var t=0.00;t<=1.00;t+=.01){
            var pt=getCubicBezierXYatT(bez.s,bez.c1,bez.c2,bez.e,t);
            if(pt.x<minX){minX=pt.x;}
            if(pt.x>maxX){maxX=pt.x;}
            if(pt.y<minY){minY=pt.y;}
            if(pt.y>maxY){maxY=pt.y;}
        }
    }
    return({x:minX,y:minY,width:maxX-minX,height:maxY-minY});
}

function getCubicBezierXYatT(startPt,controlPt1,controlPt2,endPt,T){
    var x=CubicN(T,startPt.x,controlPt1.x,controlPt2.x,endPt.x);
    var y=CubicN(T,startPt.y,controlPt1.y,controlPt2.y,endPt.y);
    return({x:x,y:y});
}

// cubic helper formula at T distance
function CubicN(T, a,b,c,d) {
    var t2 = T * T;
    var t3 = t2 * T;
    return a + (-a * 3 + T * (3 * a - a * T)) * T
    + (3 * b + T * (-6 * b + b * 3 * T)) * T
    + (c * 3 - c * 3 * T) * t2
    + d * t3;
}
```

**Determines if 2 bounding boxes (rectangles) are colliding:**

```
function Colliding(left1,top1,right1,bottom1,left2,top2,right2,bottom2){

    return(!(
        left1   > right2 ||
        right1  < left2  ||
        bottom1 < top2   ||
        top1    >bottom2
    ));

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works fine!

But I have a little problem. At the begin, the images are placed next to each other. If two images collide, they move to a new layer and the blob is drawn around the two objects, also on the new layer. But I have to move the shape to the bottom of layer, otherwise, you can't see the images. But if I do this, it is not possible to drag the blob :-/  

I updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9tB7d/1/ 

Maybe, there is another idea to put the blob to the background?

Comment: I tried it with setZIndex(0) to rect and blob, but this doesn't work, too :-/

Comment: Hups. I solved it. I use zIndex for the blob, and on 'dragend', I remove the boxes...